# Oracle SQL: How to create a full list of event history table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables for this work.

Table 1 includes all the days (365 records) from 1/1/2019 to 12/31/2019.

```
DATE
1/1/2019
1/2/2019
...
12/31/2019
```

Table 2 includes the event date and description for two different ID

```
ID   EVENT_DATE   EVENT_DESC
1    1/5/2019     APPLIED
1    2/1/2019     APPROVED
2    1/22/2019    APPLIED
2    2/11/2019    DENIED
```

How can I create a new event  history table:

```
DATE          ID    EVENT_DESC
1/1/2019      NULL  NULL
..
1/5/2019      1     APPLIED
1/6/2019      1     APPLIED
..
1/22/2019     1     APPLIED
1/22/2019     2     APPLIED
..
2/1/2019      1     APPROVED
2/1/2019      2     APPLIED
..
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure of your need but doing that will introduce a lot of duplicate data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select d.date, i.id, 
    lag(t.event_desc ignore nulls, 1, t.event_desc) over(partition by i.id order by d.date) event_desc
from table1 d
cross join (select distinct id from table2) i
left join table2 t on t.event_datae = d.date and t.id = i.id
```

Basically this generates one row per id and per date. When there is an event for that particular date, it is displayed, else the last available event is displayed.